# how to create list element only if it not exist already in batch file?

Tags: list, batch-file, if-statement

i want to create batch script which will read `*.txt` file like this one

```
05.2016 192 
04.2016 431 
05.2016 29 
12.2015 110 
12.2015 42 
12.2015 7584 
12.2015 1118 
04.2016 0 
12.2015 356 
05.2016 140 
05.2016 248 
04.2016 2012
```

and create list element only if the first token is new and add the second token to its value, 
if it is used already i want to add the second token in addition to it previous value

**for example list[04.2016] would have value 2443 (431+0+2012)**

i tried this code

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in (text.txt) do (
if pole[%%i]==nul set pole[%%i]=%%j
::else ( set pole[%%i]=pole[%%i]+%%j )
echo !pole[%%i]!
)

echo !pole[04.2016]!
echo !pole[05.2016]!
```

*( the else line is only for preview what i want to do next :-D )*

i expect that i have some mistake in the line with **IF** because when i try simplier code with only

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in (spracuj2.txt) do (
set pole[%%i]=%%j
echo !pole[%%i]!
)
```

it works fine but i need the if statements though :-P

Comment: Did you already try to replace `if pole[%%i]==nul` by `if "pole[%%i]"==""`?

Comment: Don't use `::`-style remarks within blocks of code or loops as you might get unexpected results; use `rem` instead...

Comment: `if pole[%%i]==nul` must be changed to `if defined pole[%%i]` or to `if "!pole[%%i]!"==""`; if you remove the `::`, the `if`/`else` syntax is wrong -- see `if /?`; for arithmetic operations you need the `/A` switch: `set /A pole[%%i]=pole[%%i]+%%j` or `set /A pole[%%i]+=%%j`...

Answer (score 1):

You underestimate the power of `set`. Your `if` statement does not work (and you don't need it). You have to use `set /a` to do calculations:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in (test.txt) do set /a pole[%%i]+=%%j
echo !pole[04.2016]!
echo !pole[05.2016]!
echo ----
set pole[
```

(you don't need the `if`, because `set /a var=%emptyVariable%` sets `var` to `0` (very convenient))